# Facebook Business set up as a person, and a page.  Can they be merged?

Tags: facebook

So I inherited a website that has 2 Facebook pages set up.

The business owners, not knowing any better, created a person page for the business.  This "person" later went on to start, and adminsister another page for the business in the correct way.

The problem is, the "person" page has the username desired by the business page (fb.com/businessName), and they both have "likes" that I would not like to lose.

**Update**

I just found [this link](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=18918) which explains how to convert a profile into a page. This gives me hope that I can keep the username, but brings up a new concerns.

Will this allow me to *merge* the 2 pages, keeping "likes" from each? The business page now has maybe 2x the "likes" as the profile page (~50 vs ~25). It would be a real bummer to loose any of these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **I have two Facebook Pages for the same thing. Can I merge them?**
>
> Yes, you can merge duplicate pages and/or places. To merge one page
>   into another:
>
> - Go to the page you want to keep.
> - Click the Edit Page button in the top right corner.
> - From the left column menu, click Resources.
> - Click the Merge duplicate pages link.
> - A dialogue will show pages you admin that qualify to be merged. Select the page(s) you wish to merge to the page you're on. If you're
>     merging a place and a page, they must have the same address
>     information.
>
> Please note: The page you merge will be removed from Facebook and you
>   will not be able to unmerge your pages.

[Taken from this Facebook Help Article](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=249601088403018#I-have-two-Facebook-Pages-for-the-same-thing.-Can-I-merge-them?)

It doesn't state whether this will work for a personal page and business page. I guess the only way to find out is to try it! :)

Comment: I will try to convert the personal page first, and then merge them.

Comment: There is no "Merge Duplicates" option after clicking Resources.