# Will deleting a Facebook profile free up the username?

Tags: facebook

I have a personal profile for a business as well as a business page. I plan to delete the former, but unfortunately that's the one that has the desired username. If I delete that profile, will the username become available, or will it be lost forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this thread (as recently as 2017): https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10153399860456687 the policy is that a username, once used, is never available again, even if the page that originally used it is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even your username will be free; for example:

```
www.facebook.com/username
```

After deleting your account any one can use that username, so you'll lose it if someone else registers it. If you want to retain it, deactivate your account rather than deleting it.

Comment: So, I guesse I should actually delete the personal profile and set the username on the business page asap

Comment: Also, Do you maybe have a link?  I want to be certain that I can get this username for the other page, or I can try the more roundabout convert/merge operation described in my other question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19732/facebook-business-set-up-as-a-person-and-a-page-can-they-be-merged

Comment: I guess you've already got an answer to that question you mentioned in your comment and yes perhaps you should hurry up o create a new page before someone else takes the username you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, deleting a Facebook **profile** as well as changing a profile's username makes that username available again for use.

I've tried it myself several times. However this is applicable to personal profiles only, haven't tried that with pages.

Comment: I changed my personal profile's username. Neither the username is available on my business page, nor my profile is able to retrieve that username back. do you think deleting my personal profile is worth a try?