# Change Facebook profile to page, and then merge another page with it

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

A business I am helping has a Facebook profile page (a business as a "person") and a standard Facebook business page. I'll call the profile "A" and the existing business page "B". The goal is to end up with only Facebook page B, but with A's friends as likes to that page.

I understand from [other questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19732/facebook-business-set-up-as-a-person-and-a-page-can-they-be-merged) that a profile can be converted to a page. I also understand from Facebook [help](http://www.facebook.com/help/249601088403018) that a page can be merged into another page, with the caveat that only the likes are going to come over (and yes, profile A has many more friends than page B has likes).

My idea was to do something like this:

1. Backup posts, etc. from both A and B. (I'm going to lose all content, I realize)
2. Rename B to "C".
3. Convert A to a page and give it the title B.
4. Merge C into B.

In regards to step 3, the Facebook help [says](http://www.facebook.com/help/158425527557312/) that when you convert a profile to a page, that profile username becomes the page username (i.e., part of the URL). That is fine, but I am assuming I can change the title of the new page to "B" if I want to (assuming the already existing "B" has been re-titled something else). Correct me if I am wrong.

Will this basic flow work? Even if so, would you do it differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across an [article](http://just-ask-kim.com/merge-facebook-profile-page/#.UUzgIByeNaZ) that discusses pretty much the exact process that I described above, so it seems this is feasible. The article does differ a bit from the steps I mentioned in the question. Instead of renaming B to C, it suggests renaming the profile A to page B before you convert it to a page, and then merge the two pages together. Not entirely sure how that would work exactly.

In absence of other answers or feedback, I will just go ahead and make this the answer unless something better comes a long.